# assert wrapper function

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python, pep8

So I came across this interesting problem while reviewing code:

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self, foo_name):
    self.foo_doo = getattr(foo_name, 'foo_lists', None)

  def assert_foo(self, varname):
    assert hasattr(self, 'foo_%s' % varname)

  def foobar(self):
    assert_foo('doo')
```

Wonder if wrapping assert to a customized version of your own is faster/better solution then using `assert hasattr(...)` everytime you need to make sure the attribute is present and not None?

Comment: There's no particular reason you can't - `unittest` has a number of wrappers like `assertEqual`. It depends what makes your code most readable.

Comment: Faster? Faster to type, sure. Slower to execute, obviously, since there's an extra function call involved.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasK, I see no problem. As for the speed, I think that should be negligible in most cases (in spite of the theoretical difference pointed out by @kindall), depending on how often you execute this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line will raise `NameError` unless changed to

```
self.assert_foo('doo')
```

That aside, I do not think `assert` should be used in the above code with or without the wrapper. The corrected line only checks that `self` has `.foo_doo` set, but not that it is not `None`.

```
if self.foo_doo is not None:
```

does both.

If one wants an abbreviated look-first attribute check, one could write

```
def has_foo(self, name):
    return hasattr(self, 'foo_'+name)

def foobar(self):
    if has_foo('doo'):
```

If you also want a non-`None` check, change the `has_foo` return to:

```
return getattr(self, 'foo_'+name, None) is not None
```

Beyond this, `assert` in production code should only be used to check internal logic and not runtime conditions affected by users of the code. Users can delete or disable assertions, so code should not depend on assert for its proper operation once released.

In the code above, `__init__` sets `self.foo_doo` to *something*, but the caller can subsequently delete the attribute. So both the existence and value of the attribute are user-determined run time conditions and not appropriate subjects for assertions.

The `TestCase.assertXxx` methods of `unittest` are only used for testing, and when they fail, they do more than just wrap a simple `assert`.